# Compton failing to make Cairo Dock transparent

Tags: lubuntu, cairo-dock, compton

Despite looking for a while I can't find any answers, which either means I'm doing something very stupid and obvious, or - well, I don't know.  It's probably that.

Running Lubuntu 14.04 on (sadly) an Asus eee x101ch, xcompmgr works fine making Cairo Dock transparent.  I've been reading about Compton, and thought I would give it a go - but it doesn't seem to make Cairo transparent.  The best it does is turn the black panel the same colour as the desktop - but it's certainly not transparent, as it hides other windows.

I only installed this OS a couple of days ago so in all other respects it's "as new".

Any ideas?